# ASP Gridview Failed to load viewstate.

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview

I am getting an error in asp.net 4.5 when i dynamically create a button in `GridView.ROWDATABOUND` event.

code for button:

```
Dim btn1 As New Button()
btn1.ID = "btn1"
btn1.Width = "50"
btn1.Text = "Edit"
btn1.CssClass = "AdminPageBtn"
btn1.CommandName = "Edit"
btn1.CommandArgument = "Edit"
btn1.Enabled = True
```

e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).Controls.Add(btn1)

And I'm using AJAX 4.0 too, with script manager and update panel.

that button execute the below method

```
Protected Sub gvwRoutes_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, 
                      ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs)
                Handles gvwRoutes.RowEditing
End Sub
```

when it is executed, there is an error:

`Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.`

Need a Solution..!

Comment: Try to put this button into the markup.

Comment: that would ruin the structure. this was working in a previous version where there was neither ajax nor update panel present. Now it becomes garbage and i have no idea why or what to do

Comment: You just said the anwnsear. Unfortanally Update Panel has a lot of issues, one of does is View State management. Every control must be created in Page_OnInit to give you some success!

Comment: How do i create button for a gridview in page oninit? I fine that difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to add the controls in the middle of somewhere in control collection then you'll definitely go under problems with view state. As per the MSDN [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4) of Dynamic controls in Asp.net

```
Inserting a dynamic control somewhere other than the end of the Controls collection 
can cause a corrupted view state
```

So possible solution to this could be Using the `Placeholder` in your page where you can add the dynamic controls. This will reserve the index in the middle of Control collection and will take care of the View state as well. As newly added control will have it's view state from Placeholder control.